# Hook into install email

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, functions, installation

I created a plugin that makes use of the `wp_install` method (this part is necessary for the plugin to work properly and this function needs to be called).

http://wpseek.com/function/wp_install/

Within it, the `wp_new_blog_notification` method is called to fire off the standard WordPress email right after installation (this part is not necessary for the plugin).

http://wpseek.com/function/wp_new_blog_notification/

Does anyone know if there's a way to hook into the method and stop the email from being fired?

**EDIT:**

I should also mention that within the plugin, I created a filter:

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail', array( $this, '_fix_mail' ) );
```

where the `_fix_mail` method simply looks for the strings within the `wp_new_blog_notification` and replaces them with custom ones. However, this is strictly because I can't seem to stop it from firing. A better solution would be to just not send the installation email.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the code, there is no hook to do that. But you can create your own function and remove the part that you don't need like this

```
function custom_wp_install( $blog_title, $user_name, $user_email, $public, $deprecated = '', $user_password = '', $language = '' ) {
    if ( !empty( $deprecated ) )
        _deprecated_argument( __FUNCTION__, '2.6' );

    wp_check_mysql_version();
    wp_cache_flush();
    make_db_current_silent();
    populate_options();
    populate_roles();

    update_option('blogname', $blog_title);
    update_option('admin_email', $user_email);
    update_option('blog_public', $public);

    if ( $language ) {
        update_option( 'WPLANG', $language );
    }

    $guessurl = wp_guess_url();

    update_option('siteurl', $guessurl);

    // If not a public blog, don't ping.
    if ( ! $public )
        update_option('default_pingback_flag', 0);

    /*
     * Create default user. If the user already exists, the user tables are
     * being shared among blogs. Just set the role in that case.
     */
    $user_id = username_exists($user_name);
    $user_password = trim($user_password);
    $email_password = false;
    if ( !$user_id && empty($user_password) ) {
        $user_password = wp_generate_password( 12, false );
        $message = __('<strong><em>Note that password</em></strong> carefully! It is a <em>random</em> password that was generated just for you.');
        $user_id = wp_create_user($user_name, $user_password, $user_email);
        update_user_option($user_id, 'default_password_nag', true, true);
        $email_password = true;
    } elseif ( ! $user_id ) {
        // Password has been provided
        $message = '<em>'.__('Your chosen password.').'</em>';
        $user_id = wp_create_user($user_name, $user_password, $user_email);
    } else {
        $message = __('User already exists. Password inherited.');
    }

    $user = new WP_User($user_id);
    $user->set_role('administrator');

    wp_install_defaults($user_id);

    wp_install_maybe_enable_pretty_permalinks();

    flush_rewrite_rules();

    wp_cache_flush();

    /**
     * Fires after a site is fully installed.
     *
     * @since 3.9.0
     *
     * @param WP_User $user The site owner.
     */
    do_action( 'wp_install', $user );

    return array('url' => $guessurl, 'user_id' => $user_id, 'password' => $user_password, 'password_message' => $message);
}
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid having to copy and paste the entire function and delete one line. I guess that might be the only way.